# How do I add a device to my network on the linksys ea7500 using the MAC address?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, mac-address

I have a Smart Wifi router linksys ea7500, and a proprietary microcontroler with the mac address `DE:AD:BE:EF:CA:FE`. I am not sure how to reprogram the MCU yet.

When I access the administration page for the router, Linksys recommends I read the manual for the device. I do not see any location where I can manually add a device using the mac address.

I tried setting up a guest network, but the router interface demands a password for a guest.

I tried adding a reservation using the mac address, but the unit has not connected to that yet.

Comment: If MC has ethernet port, try wired connection first, so you would be able to setup WiFi (name/pass) on microcontroller  (MC further). Allow MC to connect to  router once over DHCP then you would see it in a list of connected devices then assign to this device so called `static DHCP` (aka reservation) permanent IP address, so in a future microcontroller would pick always the same IP. If MC can't get IP address from DHCP it means it either has static IP address or simply malfunction.Try to spot on your network your device with `arp` program that comes with any OS or 3rd party utility like `fing`

Comment: What exactly are you asking how to do? Are you trying to connect your proprietary device to your wireless network without performing a “connection process” on the micro controller? There is nothing you can do on the router at all to force some device to connect just because it has a specific MAC address. You can filter devices by MAC address on your WiFi, blocking ones you don’t want. But, you can’t open up your WiFi so that something automatically connects just because it has a certain MAC address. That would make your WiFi network completely vulnerable to attack.

Comment: yes, I want to connect a proprietary device to my network, using the mac address, and not have to use a password, or login credentials. This was something i could do with my old router. Im not sure why I can not do it on this new one.